# I want the box to be deleted after is 5 times break through box

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator

I'm new to pine programming and I struggle with this for hours.
I want each drawn box to be valid until it is broken 5 times with closed candle.

```
var bool gapImbBull = na
var bool gapImbBear = na
// look for bullish GIBs 
if last_bar_index - bar_index <= 100 //shows indicator on last 100 candles
    if (open[0] > open[1] and close[0] > close[1] and open[0] > close[1] and open[0] > close[1] and low[1] >= close[0] and close[0] > open[0])
        gapImbBull := true 
    else
        gapImbBull := false
   
// look for bearish GIBS
if last_bar_index - bar_index <= 100
    if (open[0] < open[1] and close[0] < close[1] and open[0] < close[1] and low[1] >= open[0] and close[0] < open[0])
        gapImbBear := true
    else 
        gapImbBear := false


var box[] gapImbBoxes = array.new_box()
var bool[] gapImbType = array.new_bool()

var color gibColor = color.new(gibImbColorInput, imbTranspInput)
var color gibColor2 = color.new(gibImbColorInput, imbTranspInput2)



// for Gibs
if gapImbBear and showGImbalance
    array.push(gapImbBoxes, box.new(left=time[1], top=close[1], right=time, bottom=open[0], extend=extend.right, xloc=xloc.bar_time, border_color=gibColor2, bgcolor=gibColor))
    array.push(gapImbType, true)

if gapImbBull and showGImbalance
    array.push(gapImbBoxes, box.new(left=time[1], top=close[1], right=time, bottom=open[0], extend=extend.right, xloc=xloc.bar_time, border_color=gibColor2, bgcolor=gibColor))
    array.push(gapImbType, false)

// limit number of boxes allowed
if array.size(gapImbBoxes) > numberOfZonesInput
    box.delete(array.shift(gapImbBoxes))
    array.shift(gapImbType)
```

Example of what I want:
[image: there is example what i want to do]

After the box has been broken 5 times by closing candle, the box is deleted.